# How to make only one or a few cells publicly editable in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, sharing, file-sharing, google-drive-sharing

I want to publish a tool using Google Sheets that should be as easy to use as possible, so I would not like the user to have to create a copy (requiring a Google account), then editing cells in that, instead I want them to edit two cells in my file directly.

Now the problem: The best I've found so far is protecting an entire sheet except for those two cells, which at least prevents adding new rows etc., but not creating new sheets in that file. Alternatively, I could share ranges with certain mail addresses, but that would require manual action every time someone wants to use my tool (and additional steps again). I was also unable to to find any advances sharing options other than nothing/view/comment/edit and some unrelated options, like disabling printing or re-sharing.

So how do I make everyone able to edit only a few cells, nothing else?

Comment: only as you already stated. there isnt any other hidden sharing menu, but note that there is an advanced sharing option where you can disable downloading, sharing and editing per users/moederators - its under share button and then clicking on Advanced (bottom right corner of popup window)

Comment: See [Stop, limit, or change sharing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?hl=en)

Comment: @Rubén I cannot find an answer to my question on that help page.

Comment: The referred web page includes the available sharing options like disabling printing and downloading. Maybe the most relevant part is that this limitations only applies to viewers so people able to edit will be able to print and download, in other words, what you are looking for isn't possible.

Comment: Hm, too bad. Then you can write that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Rubén](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%C3%A9n)'s [comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123541/how-to-make-only-one-or-a-few-cells-publicly-editable-in-google-sheets#comment111491_123541), there is no way to do this. Google Sheets files can only be completely uneditable or they allow creating new sheets.

This in my opinion a bug or just an oversight and I've reported it using the "feedback" menu, in case that even goes anywhere.